# Perl Strip Regex For URI

Tags: regex, perl, cgi

I'm trying to strip out all https, http, www, /, : and . out of a domain name to create a user account folder on my system. So what I need is to make a URL that looks like this "https://www.My-Domain.com/" into "My-Domaincom" I'm close but just cant seem to get it to work.

```
our $DomainAccount = lc($ENV{HTTP_REFERER});
  $DomainAccount =~ s/^http:\/\/|^https:\/\///;
  $DomainAccount =~ s/^www\.|(/.)//;
```

Comment: Maybe `$DomainAccount =~ s/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?//i;`?

Comment: Nope I still end up with: My-Domain.com/

Comment: Aha, you need to get to the first `/`, use `$DomainAccount =~ s/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/]+).*/$1/i;`

Comment: Nope that get me this :Useless use of non-destructive substitution (s///r) in void context.

Comment: I updated my comment, see my answer (I used that `/r` in my testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure you match the `http://` or `https://` that is optionally followed with `www.`, match *and capture* the host URL part up to the first `/` and then match the rest, and replace with the backreference to the first capture group `$1`, and in order to remove `.` from the `host.com` you need to use a second capturing group like this:

```
$DomainAccount =~ s/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/.]+)\.([^\/.]+).*/$1$2/i;
```

Output for `"https://www.My-Domain.com/"`: `My-Domaincom`

See the **[regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pQ6qH6/1)**.

Note I added a case-insensitive flag `/i` just to make sure the pattern can handle `HTTP://` casing, too.

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `https?:\/\/` - a literal character sequence `http://` or `https://`
- `(?:www\.)?` - one or zero occurrences of a literal character sequence `www.`
- `([^\/.]+)` - Group 1: one or more characters other than `/` and `.`
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `([^\/.]+)` - Group 2: one or more characters other than `/` and `.`
- `.*` - rest of the line

**To address choroba's comment**, here is a 2 step solution that will work with URLs containing more than one dot in the host part:

```
$DomainAccount =~ s/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/]+).*/$1/i;
$DomainAccount =~ s/\.//g;
```

Comment: Yes, as the example in the question. I have added a two-step solution to address such situations. See this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/omKTeR).

Answer (score 1):

[URI](http://p3rl.org/URI) can help you, but you still have to remove the `www` yourself:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use URI;

my $url = 'URI'->new('https://www.My-Domain.com/');
my $account = $url->host;
$account =~ s/^[^.]*\.// while 1 != $account =~ tr/.//;
$account =~ s/\.//;
print $account, "\n";
```

This only leaves the top and second level domains in the result (try with e.g. `http://some.very.long.domain.name.com`).

Comment: I hope my regex explanation makes it easier to understand. There is nothing difficult, really, no lookarounds, no `\G` or `\K` operators, no recursion, just plain character classes, grouping, anchors and quantifiers. Just the standard regex kit. Your suggestion is also very good, +1.